# Real Analysis: Show the sequence $a_n=10n$ is not convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove this by contradiction so $|10n- λ| \geqslant \epsilon$ but I don’t know where to go from here as in the examples an epsilon is chosen but with no explanation as to why.

Comment: You want to show that there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for all $N\in\mathbb N$, there exists $n\geq N$ such that $|10n-\lambda|\geq\varepsilon$ (where $\lambda$ is a fixed real number). Take any $\varepsilon$ and it will work in this case since $10n\to\infty$ (e.g. take $\varepsilon=1$).

Comment: In this case it is easier to show for every $M \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that for every $n > N$ it satisfies $|10n |\ge M$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the examples you refer to, an $\epsilon$ is chosen because

- Basically any $\epsilon$ would work
- You only need one to work
- You do need one to work

Given a number $\lambda$, the definition of "$a_n$ converges to $\lambda$" is

> For any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N\in \Bbb N$ such for any $n>N$ we have $$|a_n-\lambda|<\epsilon$$

Negating this, the definition of "$a_n$ doesn't converge to $\lambda$" becomes

> There is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $N\in \Bbb N$ there is an $n>N$ such that $$|a_n-\lambda|\geq \epsilon$$

So as you can see, as long as they can prove that a single such $\epsilon$ exists, they will have proven that $\lambda$ is not the limit of the sequence. One common way to prove that an $\epsilon$ exists is to pick a specific number and show that that works.

You need to pick an $\epsilon$ which is small enough. If $1$ works, most people would probably pick that. Failing that, usually one would go for $\epsilon = \frac1k$ for some natural number $k$. And if one $\epsilon$ works, then any smaller $\epsilon$ also automatically works.

Some times, I like to pick a smaller-than-strictly-necessary $\epsilon$ in order to ensure that we get $|a_n-\lambda|>\epsilon$ rather than $|a_n-\lambda|\geq \epsilon$, because I like that better (for instance, for $b_n = (-1)^n, \lambda = 0$, then $\epsilon = \frac12$ is good enough but I prefer to use $\frac13$). But you don't need to do that.

Comment: So if I chose $\epsilon=1$, would it prove this by saying $|10n-\lambda$| = 10n-$\lambda$ >10n>10>1=$\epsilon$ ?

Comment: @Becca That's the basic idea, yes. Except that $10n-\lambda \not > 10n$. Also you're skipping over $N$. So you need to pick $n$ large enough so that 1) $n>N$, and 2) $10n-\lambda > \epsilon$. It's not difficult to find, but you ought to go through the motions carefully for the sake of practice.

Comment: Does this value for N need to be explicit? Or because it’s for any N, would you pick something like n=N+1 so N+1>N ? Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: @Becca Look at the definition of "doesn't converge". It says "for any $N$". So you don't get to choose one. You are given an arbitrary $N$. And yes, $n=N+1$ would work much of the time, but you also have to make sure you take care of $10n-\lambda\geq\epsilon$. That _might_ require an even larger $n$ than that. Once you've found an $n$ large enough for both requirements, you are done.